# Dart Language: event.target

Tags: web-applications, dart

First, I would like to thank you all for the support.

I have a question regarding event triggers (event.target). The thing is, I have five buttons inside a webpage and all of them have unique ids (like #button1, #button2). The querySelector of all of them starts the same function: buttonClicked.

But I have a problem using the same function for all of the buttons: I can't identify which one was pressed, unless doing a check over "event.target.id". In this case, I would have to write a "switch" or a "if" to determinate it, but I would like to know if there's any other way I could define/determinate the pressed button without using "switch" or "if" or doing specific functions to each button.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The question is what you want to acomplish. Why do you need the same handler for all of your functions?

Can you post the code you already have?

Comment: @Robert The code is a little big. But I can explain it: I have 32 buttons (that are actually table cells) that I want to do the same thing when clicked. But I need to know which one was clicked in order to save that cell information. As I said, I know that I can do a switch, but with 32 cells it's a little extensive.

Comment: What does "save that cell information" mean? How do you save it? Put .text into a map and that's what you need the information for? Explain in more detail how you save it, please.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I will create a new object from (example) class "Cell" with name cell1 and it will contain the cell's text and other information.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal code example that shows what you try to do. In my opinion it is not clear what you would do in the swith and therefore it's hard to show you better ways.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer code added!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are doing this. This will simply call the function when any button is clicked.

```dart
querySelectorAll('...').onClick.listen(buttonClicked);
```

Of course you can do this:

```dart
['button1', ..., 'buttonN'].forEach((String id) {
  querySelector('#$id').onClick.listen((MouseEvent e) {
    Specific code here...
    id is still valid
  });
});
```

This iterates over a list of strings, queries the button and assigns a onClick listener.

Or even:

```dart
['button1', ..., 'buttonN'].forEach((String id) {
  querySelector('#$id').onClick.listen((MouseEvent e) => someButtonClicked(id));
});
```

That does almost the same thing as the one before, but now we return a new function when as the handler (=>) calls and "returns" the value from someButtonClicked.

Event Handlers:

```dart
buttonClicked(MouseEvent e) {

}

someButtonClicked(String id) {

}
```

But it really depends what you want to do!

See also:

- https://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-6.html
- https://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-7.html
- https://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/

For saving information you could do (assuming the button is in the cell):

When a button is clicked, you get the text from the cell and create a new object. Is that what you need?

```dart
querySelectorAll('td button').onClick.listen((MouseEvent e) {
  ButtonElement button = (ButtonElement) e.target;
  Cell c = new Cell(button.id, button.parent.text);
});
```

Regards
Robert

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you explain the alternatives that you gave me or post a link to some tutorial about that?

Comment: And I forgot to say that you assumed it right: I'm doing "querySelectorAll('...').onClick.listen(buttonClicked);".

Comment: Hey, I edited my post. I also posted a possible solution for the text saving stuff

Comment: As far as I know you need the foreEach also for the querySelectorAll() result `querySelectorAll('...').forEach((b) => b.onClick.listen(clickHandler));`

Comment: @Felipe Thanks for the code. I still dont get why you need to know the button and need a if/switch. Why isn't it enough what I proposed?

Comment: @Robert I did a terrible job at explaining my problem... Sorry! I'm trying an alternative here and, if it works, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

quer

```dart
ySelector("#pos1").onClick.listen(positionClick);
  querySelector("#pos2").onClick.listen(positionClick);
  querySelector("#pos3").onClick.listen(positionClick);
  querySelector("#pos4").onClick.listen(positionClick);
  querySelector("#pos5").onClick.listen(positionClick);
  document
        ..getElementById("options_table_row_1").querySelectorAll("td").onClick.listen(optionClick)
        ..getElementById("options_table_row_2").querySelectorAll("td").onClick.listen(optionClick)
        ..getElementById("options_table_row_3").querySelectorAll("td").onClick.listen(optionClick)
        ..getElementById("options_table_row_4").querySelectorAll("td").onClick.listen(optionClick)
        ..getElementById("options_table_row_5").querySelectorAll("td").onClick.listen(optionClick)
        ..getElementById("options_table_row_6").querySelectorAll("td").onClick.listen(optionClick)
        ..getElementById("options_table_row_7").querySelectorAll("td").onClick.listen(optionClick)
        ..getElementById("o
```

ptions_table_row_8").querySelectorAll("td").onClick.listen(optionClick);

You should add a class to each elements/buttons that you want to be notified about click events
which allows you to do

```dart
querySelectorAll('.pos-buttons').forEach((pb) => pb.onClick.listen(positionClick));
querySelectorAll('.opt-buttons').forEach((pb) => pb.onClick.listen(optionClick));
```

The content of the `positionClick` and `optionClick` seem to be already simplified. I can't see a `switch` or many `if` statements.

This is practicall what Robert already explained.